# Enable external boot devices in UEFI

Tags: multi-boot, uefi

I own an HP Pavilion 5 Notebook which came pre installed with Windows 8. I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my system via a LIVEUSB. 
But my system doesn't detect the LiveUSB during boot. My boot order is proper, with external USB in the first place, but the system just boots into Windows directly.

Also I observed that when I turn on Legacy mode, the USB is detected. But then I have to install Ubuntu in CSM mode instead of EFI, which causes boot problems later on.

Is there a way to detect my external boot options in UEFI as well?
P.S. Secure Boot was disabled during the booting.

Answer (score 0):

This might simply be due to Secure Boot being enabled. Go into the BIOS > Security settings and disable it.

[Secure Boot (Windows 8) on the HP website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03653226)

Also, after a bid of digging around, I saw that unfortunately you might have quite a few issues getting this to work when Windows 8 has been preinstalled (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) on askubuntu). It might be worth going through all the suggested fixes and see if that helps.

Comment: I disabled Secure boot. This doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Neil Ok, answer updated :)

Comment: Thanks @user1301428. But the link you suggested was the link I had visited first when I had started with the installation. :) I tried everything from that tutorial and met with different problems. So I wanted to know whether it was possible to somehow detect external sources in EFI. Is there any way, any at all, to do this? Or is it just impossible?

Comment: @Neil how did you create the external live usb?

Comment: With YUMI Multiboot software available at pendrivelinux.com

Comment: Just to have some more details, is it possible for you to create a Live CD and see if that works?

Comment: Exactly what I thought of doing. :). I'll keep you posted @user1301428

Answer (score 0):

YUMI probably didn't prepare an EFI-compatible USB flash drive. In most cases, the most reliable way to prepare a USB flash drive is with `dd`, as in:

```
sudo dd=infile.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Change `infile.iso` and `/dev/sdc` as appropriate for your system.